# deleting an entry from an array in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

We have a very complex collection structure.
I want to delete an entry from it. I am new to mongodb.

The sample collection is as follows,

```
{
  "rootid": "1",
  "projects": [
    {
      "projectId": "2",
      "proxies": [
        {
          "proxyId": "4",
          "config": {
            "pipeline": [
              {
                "pipelineId": "12",
                "desc": "pipeline"
              },
              {
                "pipelineId": "14",
                "desc": "pipeline1234"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete an  entry from pipeline embedded collection, if it matches the criteria.

Example:
if `"rootid": "1" ,"projectId": "2", "proxyId": "4",  "pipelineId": "12"` then I want to delete first entry from pipeline array.

We are using spring boot as a framework.
If some one helps with mongo query I will try to convert it with spring mongoTemplate.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html#examples) combined with [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to achieve this.

```
db.collection.update({
  "rootid": "1"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "projects.$[project].proxies.$[proxy].config.pipeline": {
      pipelineId: "12"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "project.projectId": "2"
    },
    {
      "proxy.proxyId": "4"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ir5U3E_OTcP)